# spring cloud stream 'bindingService' error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix, turbine, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to implement Turbine AMQP to consolidate all the stream from multiple services to Hystrix Dashboard.

So I added couple of dependencies to the gradle file and after that I am not able to start my application for some reason.

LOGS from startup where i see the exception.

```
[LogMessage=Application startup failed]
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bindingService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/ChannelBindingServiceConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderFactory]: Error creating bean with name 'binderFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/BinderFactoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderTypeRegistry]: Error creating bean with name 'binderTypeRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/BinderFactoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderTypeRegistry]: Factory method 'binderTypeRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot create binder factory, no `META-INF/spring.binders` resources found on the classpath; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'binderTypeRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/BinderFactoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderTypeRegistry]: Factory method 'binderTypeRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot create binder factory, no `META-INF/spring.binders` resources found on the classpath; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'binderFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/BinderFactoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderTypeRegistry]: Error creating bean with name 'binderTypeRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/BinderFactoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderTypeRegistry]: Factory method 'binderTypeRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot create binder factory, no `META-INF/spring.binders` resources found on the classpath; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'binderTypeRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/BinderFactoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderTypeRegistry]: Factory method 'binderTypeRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot create binder factory, no `META-INF/spring.binders` resources found on the classpath
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.bbtransact.icp.api.associations.boot.UserApplication.main(UserApplication.java:20) [bin/:na]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'binderTypeRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/BinderFactoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderTypeRegistry]: Factory method 'binderTypeRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot create binder factory, no `META-INF/spring.binders` resources found on the classpath
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderTypeRegistry]: Factory method 'binderTypeRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot create binder factory, no `META-INF/spring.binders` resources found on the classpath
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot create binder factory, no `META-INF/spring.binders` resources found on the classpath
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BinderFactoryConfiguration.binderTypeRegistry(BinderFactoryConfiguration.java:100) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.0.0.RC1.jar:1.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BinderFactoryConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b9b6d96.CGLIB$binderTypeRegistry$1(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.0.0.RC1.jar:1.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BinderFactoryConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b9b6d96$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d1bb81f1.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.0.0.RC1.jar:1.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:355) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BinderFactoryConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b9b6d96.binderTypeRegistry(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.0.0.RC1.jar:1.0.0.RC1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
```

Here is my .Gradle I added dependencies for hystrix, hystrix-ampqp,starter-bus-amqp.

```
buildscript {

    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.3.0.RELEASE'
    }
    
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
}

    dependencies {
        classpath ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
        classpath ("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.2.RELEASE")
        classpath ("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34")
        classpath ("org.sonarqube.gradle:gradle-sonarqube-plugin:1.1")
    }
}

repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
            url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot"
            url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone"
        }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management' 
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
apply plugin: "jacoco"
apply plugin: "sonar-runner"


group    = 'com.api'

def build_version=project.properties['build_version'] ?: "SNAPSHOT"
version  = "${build_version}"

ext.packaging = 'jar'

jar {
   baseName = "userassociations-v1"
}


sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

sourceSets {
    generated {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/generated']
        }
    }
}


configurations {
    providedRuntime
     querydslapt
}

jacoco {
   
    reportsDir = file("build/tmp/jacoco.exec")
}

test{
    ignoreFailures = true    
}

sonarqube {
  properties {
    property "sonar.projectName", "User-associations-V1"
    property "sonar.projectKey", "org.sonarqube:User-associations-V1"
    property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
    property "sonar.host.url", "${sonar_host}"
    property "sonar.login", "${sonar_username}"
    property "sonar.password", "${sonar_password}"
    property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "build/jacoco/test.exec"
    property "sonar.java.source property", "1.8"
           
  }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports { 
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-parent:Brixton.RC1" 
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile         ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile         ("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka")
    compile         ("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client")
    compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix:1.0.6.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp:1.0.6.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-amqp:1.0.6.RELEASE")
    compile         ("org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java:sonar-jacoco-plugin:2.3")
    compile         ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile         ("org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.2")
    compile         ("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34")
    compile         ("org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.2.2.RELEASE")
    compile         ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    providedRuntime ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    testCompile     ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") 
    querydslapt     ("org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:5.0.5.Final")
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:1.0.0.M1'
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-core:1.0.0.M1' 
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers ('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8')
    }
}

task generateQueryDSL(type: JavaCompile, group: 'build', description: 'Generates the QueryDSL query types') {
    source = sourceSets.main.java
    classpath = configurations.compile + configurations.querydslapt
    options.compilerArgs = [
            "-proc:only"
    ]
    destinationDir = sourceSets.generated.java.srcDirs.iterator().next()
}

compileJava {
    dependsOn generateQueryDSL
    source generateQueryDSL.destinationDir
}

compileGeneratedJava {
    dependsOn generateQueryDSL
    options.warnings = false
    classpath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}

clean {
    delete sourceSets.generated.java.srcDirs
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.9'
}
```

Any help is appreciated I have been stuck for a while now.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? I have the same error message. What I try to do is to have Hystrix dashboard and Turbine stream aggregator in one application

Comment: I did but I had some problems with logs they say its fixed now but I haven't tried it again. we end up not using turbine... check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014311/too-many-logs-getting-generated-for-hystrix-amqp it is a dependency thing which i think is still messed up on mine.... let me know if you need me to paste my full dependency.

Answer (score 13):

Add this to your pom under dependencies,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This is for RabbitMQ binder

Answer (score 4):

Check whether you have Spring Cloud Stream rabbit binder dependency in your classpath. The binder is responsible for binding the spring-cloud-stream channels to your message broker.

For rabbit:
`org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit:version`

Comment: I didn't had that dependency so I added it and still the same exception on startup.... but when i remove the amqp dependency all works fine.